# ifxnjs not supporting for the NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64

Tags: informix

I have the Node.js version 10.13.0 and i have installed the ifxnjs and when tried to connect to the informix database i am getting the below error. i have to run my test cases using the node version 10 because the dev code is running on that version and i have to run my test cases against the dev code. Can anyone help me in resolving the below error? Does ifxnjs supports the node version 10.13.0.? Any help is appreciated.

```
Error: The module '\\?\C:\Project\node_modules\ifxnjs\build\Release\ifx_njs_bind.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:717:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at bindings (C:\Project\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:81:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\node_modules\ifxnjs\lib\odbc.js:33:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
```

Comment: Same here for Node v11.9.0 but requiring NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67 against 57 like you.

Answer (score 0):

We will plan to release this version soon. Look like you are on Windows we will provide priority for that then.

Comment: hello do you support node verison 14?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you have upgraded nodejs and you are trying to use a node module compiled with the old version of node in the new version.

Simple solution should be to remove all the packages and install them again

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
npm i
```

If this doesn't fix your problem you can try to rebuild the package. This command download again the sources from internet and rebuild them.

```
npm rebuild ifxnjs --build-from-source
```

In some cases I still have the problem and the solution was to manually rebuild the module

```
cd node_modules/ifxnjs
node-pre-gyp rebuild
```

This forced the node-pre-gyp tool (the tool used by node to compila binary modules) to take the correct version of node.

These examples works if you use npm, if you are using yarn the command are pretty much the same.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried reinstallation and rebuild --from-source without luck. Using `node-pre-gyp` results in an error that the package is not pre-gyp ready due to missing `binary` property in package.json. Do I have to (or is it possible to) add this property manually?